# How do i add xfade transition to a batch of videos using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm currently trying to concatenate multiple videos in a folder using FFmpeg. I've successfully applied a xfade transition between two videos using the following command: However, I'm facing **two** challenges:

**Applying xfade to multiple videos:** I want to extend this process to apply the xfade transition between all videos in the folder and save it as a single video.

**Audio issue after transition:** While the visual transition works seamlessly, I've noticed that the audio is muted as soon as the transition finishes in the output video. Is there a modification I can make to the FFmpeg command to ensure that the audio remains synchronized with the video throughout the output?

This is the command i am currently using:

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.mp4 -filter_complex "xfade=transition=fade:duration=0.25:offset=4.5" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import os,subprocess,math
def get_length(filename):
  result=subprocess.run(["ffprobe", "-v", "error", "-show_entries",
                        "format=duration", "-of",
                        "default=nw=1:nk=1", filename],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
  return float(result.stdout)

LST=[]
DIR="/mnt/public/upload/video/"
for f in os.listdir(DIR):
  if (f.endswith(".mp4")):
    print(f)
    LST.append(f)

FLV=''
FLA=''
OFS=0
XFD=0.25
CNT=0

INP=[]
f=DIR+LST[0]
INP.append(f' -i "{f}"')
PDV='[0:v]'
PDA='[0:a]'

for i in range(len(LST)-1):
  OFS=OFS+get_length(f)-XFD
  FLV+=f'{PDV}'
  FLA+=f'{PDA}'
  CNT=i+1
  PDV=f'[v{CNT}]'
  PDA=f'[a{CNT}]'
  FLV+=f'[{CNT}:v]xfade=transition=pixelize:offset={OFS}:duration={XFD}{PDV};'
  FLA+=f'[{CNT}:a]acrossfade=d={XFD}{PDA}'
  if i < len(LST)-2:
    FLA+=";"
  f=DIR+LST[i+1]
  INP.append(f' -i "{f}"')

s='ffmpeg'
for t in INP:
  s=s+t
s=s+f' -filter_complex "{FLV}{FLA}" -map {PDV} -map {PDA} -c:v h264_nvenc -cq 18 -c:a aac -q:a 4 -map_metadata -1 /tmp/output.mp4 -y -hide_banner'
print(s)
os.system(s)
os.system(f'mpv /tmp/output.mp4')
```